# Reload particular section on button click in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am trying to reload a particular section on button click in swift 4.For that,I am using following code:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView:CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseCell") as! CustomCell
        let dict:[String:Any]=array[section]
        let firstKey = Array(dict.keys)[0]
        headerView.categoryLabel.text=firstKey
        headerView.categoryLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        currentSection=section
        print("value of section and current section here %@%@",section,currentSection)
        let tapRecognizer = UIButton()
        tapRecognizer.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y:10, width:self.tableView.frame.size.width, height:50)
        //tapRecognizer.backgroundColor=UIColor.red
        tapRecognizer.tag=section
        tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapOnHeaderView(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        headerView.addSubview(tapRecognizer)
        return headerView;
    }


@objc func tapOnHeaderView(_sender:UIButton){
        print("value of sender tag","\(_sender.tag)")
        onReload = true
        print("value of index vala tag",IndexSet(integer: _sender.tag))
        let sectionToReload = 0
        let indexSet: IndexSet = [sectionToReload]

        self.tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
    }

extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if(indexPath.section==0){
            if(!onReload){
                return 0
            }else{
                return 40
            }}
        else{
            if(!onReload){
                return 0
            }else{
                return 40
            }
        }
    }
```

When I click on any button ,it is expected that only section 0 gets reload. But, infact when I click on button section 0 and section 1 both gets reloaded.Kindly help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: you should track sender.tag and then you need to reload. First, cross verify whether your button added to header view and present of top of header view by setting background color

Comment: Where are you seeing that section 1 *"gets reloaded"*? You are showing `heightForRowAt`, which will get called for every row any time the tableview needs to recalculate the full height of the table. Are you seeing `cellForRowAt` ***also*** being called for all rows in all sections?

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc func tapOnHeaderView(_sender:UIButton){
        print("value of sender tag","\(_sender.tag)")
        onReload = true
        print("value of index vala tag",IndexSet(integer: _sender.tag))
      
        self.tableView.reloadSections([0], with: .automatic)
    }
```

Please replace with this code and check whether it works for you